# Edit documents in PHP / JQuery web application

Tags: php, jquery, excel, ms-word, editor

I'm building a storage application using PHP and JQuery and i need to edit some types of files (docs, word, excel and maybe pdf) via browser.

I know i could use a WYSIWYG editor but i need a powerfull editor and if possibile it should be open and free... Maybe i'm asking too much but this is my first time with a big project and i didn't have problems like this in the past.

What's the best way to that? Is there any library to edit "office" files online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I see as the main problem: You're dealing with at least one different library per file type, not to mention dealing with the individual functions required by those filetypes.  In other words, excel is going to have different functions and requirements than word, both of which you'll need to accommodate and write for.  If you're still dead set on writing this thing yourself I would pick one file type to deal with (.docx, .xlsx, etc) and get that working with a library like PHPExcel, and then start adding in more filetypes for that particular piece.

Or, you know, you could use google docs :)